# How to Hide or Delete Files created by Vim in Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

Whenever I open a file with Vim, the program automatically creates a copy of the file ending with a tilde~

When I'm done editing a few files, the folder is littered with extraneous files ending in ~

Is it possible to have Vim automatically remove said files? Or as an alternative, is it possible to have Windows hide them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim#Backup_Files):

> **Backup Files**
>
> Vim by default creates a backup of an edited file in the same directory as the file called filename~. To prevent clutter, many users tell vim to use a backup directory:
>
> ```
> set backupdir=~/.vim/backup,/tmp
> ```
>
> Or, it's possible to even disable this behaviour:
>
> ```
> set nobackup
> set nowritebackup
> set noswapfile    ! (additionally disable swap files)
> ```

Comment: i put these backupfiles to $TEMP, otherwise +1

Comment: I didn't write that article there, I just quoted.

Comment: What file should I write these lines to?

Answer (score 1):

Also see my ["autohide" plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4505) for hiding those pesky files that oh-so-occasionally become a life saver.